# Delay in bootstrap toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a menu bar using bootstrap. In the responsive mode, when the toggle menu is activated, the menu list items comes up quickly while the background container comes with a delay. Similarly when the toggle mode is deactivated, the container disappears while the menu items disappear with a delay. I have uploaded a video of this issue here: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwJk1FZoR5hXa3VsaHM4QTF0TDQ/view?usp=sharing) 

Kindly, please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Without seeing the code, we aren't able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your #custom-collapse in the main navigation section of your css has the overflow set to visible remove that and it should work fine.

```
#custom-collapse {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If you put the overflow to visible to remove the scrollbar you should maybe try

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Comment: It did the trick. Yes I made the overflow to visible to remove the scrollbar but you also handled that part. Thank you. :)